# Using IUS repos with CentOS5 and Webmin, how should I set up Yum Priorities?

Tags: centos5, yum, repository

Following hobodave's excellent answer to this question - [Upgrade Centos 5 tot PHP 5.2 or 5.3 [recommended way?]](https://serverfault.com/questions/111458/upgrade-centos-5-tot-php-5-2-or-5-3-recommended-way) - I'm just wondering how I should set up my Yum Priorities so that IUS takes precedent over packages in the CentOS repos. I'm unsure of which repo does what (although intuition tells me that the Base repo is fairly important, so I've set that to priority=1).

Additionally, I use Webmin/ Virtualmin. Am I best setting up the IUS repos, Yum Priorities and installing PHP/ MySQL prior to installing Virtualmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUS is not using conflicting package names so this is not an issue.
Ranking it higher or lower won't make a difference.
You need to specify that you want a IUS package (e.g. `php53u`, `mysql51`, etc.).

See here: http://iuscommunity.org/FAQs#Why_are_IUS_Packages_named_differently

Comment: Sure - I get that, but when I removed 'php' from my system and used Yum to install 'php53', it installed it from a repo called 'base', which I assume is the CentOS Base repo. When I removed 'mysql', I used Yum to install 'mysql51', which installed from a repo called 'ius'. Even changing the priorities so that IUS is set to 1 and Base  to a higher number, it still opts to use the repo called 'base' to install php53.

Comment: Yes, like I wrote, the IUS PHP 5.3 package is called `php53u` (with an extra **u**) so that it doesn't conflict with the base package `php53`.

Comment: Ah, I see now - sorry, I thought php53 was the name also used by IUS (seems odd that it's the only PHP version in the repo with 'u' at the end).